# Ternary operator issues with List methods in VS2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ternary-operator

In VS2008, it seems the use of Find, FirstOrDefault and similar methods inside a ternary operation has a big issue.
Given the following very basic example:

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
myList.Add(new MyClass() { SomeField = "Mr" });
myList.Add(new MyClass() { SomeField = "Mrs" });
myList.Add(new MyClass() { SomeField = "Ms" });
```

The following does not work (or it is the best to say: it gives me null):

```
MyClass data = (myList != null) ? myList.Find(x => x.SomeField == "Ms") : null;
```

If I put myList.Find(x => x.SomeField == "Ms") in a method and call the method instead of just callign Find in the operation, I will be given a not-null value!
The above would also work for simple types, like int, lets say:

```
int i = (1 < 2) ? 1 : 0;
```

My question is: why? What is happening when using List methods here?

(One thing to note: if you exchange the Find part with the null, the result  will still be null, so the problem is not with myList != null.)

Comment: Not able to reproduce.

Comment: I'd be very happy to test it - when provided with a [mcve]. Until that point, there's not a lot we can do.

Comment: Setting the target framework to .NET 3.5 (VS 2015) I am able to reproduce this using the provided code. It works in a higher version. Using .Where(...).FirstOrDefault() with .NET 3.5 does work. Just not Find(...). Strange, never encountered this before.

Comment: We did some additional tests. It seems like the lazy loading "issue". As long as you do not reference on a field inside MyClass, the class looks like null. But even if you check if data is null it seems like then your actual data will be fetched into the data instance.

Comment: @Mark the problem is with VS2008, not 20015, however the target fw is 3.5 here too.

Comment: I just tried it with frameworks 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0 and 4.5 using VS 2012 and all versions work as expected... data is not null and contains the expected item (with `"Ms"`)

Comment: @Daniel I see now it's indeed the debugger that behaves differently: The watch says null in 3.5 but Console.Writing it actually does give a non-null result.

Comment: @musefan Add a breakpoint to the code to anywhere BEFORE referencing any field of data. Hover your mousr over data, so the IDE should say 'null'. Though, actually it is not null, it just have not been fetched. I am not sure if this is the anywer on my qeuestion...? Seems like it is...

Comment: @Mark I am happy to add this as answer, because this is what I found as well. Thank you!

Comment: I am not referencing any of the fields at all. I am adding a break point after the `MyClass data = ...` line and hover it with mouse and it is not null... I mean, you're not trying to check it *before* the line is executed are you??

Comment: Of course I am not. I dont have VS2012 here, only 2013, so I give it a try there as too.

Comment: No, in VS2013 with fw 3.5 I dont have this issue.
@Mark please copy your commnt as answer so I can mark it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be an issue with the debugger when targeting .NET 3.5 (tested in VS 2015). The debugger says null but after doing something with the variable the debugger shows the expected value. When targeting a higher version (tested .NET 4.5.2) the debugger shows the non-null value at the first breakpoint already.

.NET 3.5:

[image: NULL in debugger at first breakpoint]
[image: Not NULL in debugger at the second breakpoint]

.NET 4.5.2:

[image]

Comment: I think this happens because of "Lazy loading".